# How to pass props on Pseudo-elements with styled components?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

To be more specific I need help passing props on `content:" "`
Here is my example:

```
  &::after {
  content: "test";
  color: ${props => props.color};
  background: ${props => (props.bg ? "green" : "blue")};
}
```

Here is the component:

```
   <StyledBox bg="red" color="green" text="webpack">
      <Webpack />
    </StyledBox>
```

If I pass this in content is not working:

```
${props => props.text}
```

Any idea what would be the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Wow...I'm not sure if this is the right syntax and solution but is working if I wrap up the content props in quotes like this :

```
content:'${props => props.text}';
```